# Debug libraries of boost getting used in Release mode in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have written a DLL that uses boost extensively in its implementation. I have both release and debug version of boost libraries with me libboost_thread-vc80-mt-1_40.lib, libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_40.lib. I am using Visual studio to build my code and using auto-linking.
When i build the DLL in debug version it links itself with libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_40.lib which is expected, but when i am building my DLL in release mode it stills tries to link it with libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_40.lib instead of libboost_thread-vc80-mt-1_40.lib. I am using /MD while building in release mode.
I am not sure what i am missing in this, can someone please point me that.

Comment: This is automatic, done by boost/config/auto_link.hpp and a #pragma comment directive.  The simple explanation that you still have one or more .obj or .lib files that was compiled with /MT instead of /MD.  Grep the files for "/MT" if you have no idea which one that might be.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried /MT instead of /MD?

Comment: i don't have mts boost libraries, so i can't use that option.

Answer (score 0):

Look if there is in the release configuration a Preprocessor Definitions with the word debug, this has to be deleted if it exist.